# Squeak SMTPs on Linux

Tags: linux, ssl, smtp, smalltalk, squeak

I am using the Squeak 5 class SecureSMTPClient to send e-Mails over SSL/TLS.

It works fine on my Windows machine (thanks to the answer to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619992/squeak-securesmtpclient-to-send-html-email/37628297)).

However, on Linux i get:

```
Error: primitiveSSLCreate failed
```

And it prints in a console (but only the first time the image attempts to send the mail):

```
# ioLoadModule(/home/squeak5vm/SqueakSSL):
  /home/squeak5vm/SqueakSSL: undefined symbol: clock_gettime
```

Squeak "primitives" are functions that talk to the platform and libraries. My guess is, that this Linux does not provide some version of some SSL/TLS library that Squeak expects. But what exactly *does* Squeak expect?

---

Additional infos:

The output of `ldd /home/squeak5vm/SqueakSSL` is:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7757000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xb7392000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7758000)
```

Comment: a downvote? without giving a reason?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem might be. SSL is provided by the SqueakSSL VM plugin. First of all, check if you have that plugin (should be near your VM with stuff like FilePlugin etc.) If it's there, then the next thing is probably to look at your system: do you have OpenSSL? Which version? We also need to know which Linux you're on and if it's 32 or 64-bit.

Comment: @MaxLeske I have the standard Squeak 5 download from squeak.org. The file "SqueakSSL" is in the VM's directory (file size 9,228,209). Not sure about OpenSSL, that is why I am asking which native libraries (in which versions) Squeak is expecting. (My Linux is a 64bit one)

Comment: Is your Windows machine 32-bit or 64-bit? My first wildish guess is that maybe Squeak only works with the 32-bit version of the required libraries.

Comment: @lurker My windows is 64 bit too

Comment: I checked that OpenSSL is as current as my apt-get will give me. It would be nice if there were some info about which libraries Squeak needs (dep. on situation) and starting at which versions.

Comment: I found another error-message (clock_gettime, see above) that occurs only the first time per image-run that the image tries to send a mail.

Comment: The VM was upgraded to use a newer libc version and there may be problems with older ones (< 2.15). What version do you have?

Comment: I dont know how to find out which libc-version i have (in terminal-only Linux) but I already had to provide a new 32-bit libc (on my 64-bit Linux) 6 months ago following the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660201/getting-the-new-squeak-5-to-run-on-64-bit-linux

Comment: Try `getconf GNU_LIBC_VERSION`

Comment: @lurker thank you: `glibc 2.11.1`  (but I dont know if this is for the 64-bit version that usually runs on this machine or the additional 32-bit version I had to install 6 months ago)

Comment: Can you please give the output of `ldd /home/squeak5vm/SqueakSSL`?

Comment: @Tobias Added that info into the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of the SqueakSSL plugin you are using is compiled against OpenSSL, which in turn required `clock_gettime`.

Note the that the `man`page says

```
 Link with -lrt (only for glibc versions before 2.17).
```

Apparently, your SqueakSSL binary was compiled on a system later than glibc 2.17.

Here are some options:

1. Try the SqueakSSL binary from https://github.com/squeak-smalltalk/squeakssl/releases which are statically linked against LibreSSL. Note: They might be some weeks out of date.
2. See whether you could use an updated Linux version with glibc >= 2.17
3. Try something like re-linking or pre-loading (see [How to relink existing shared library with extra object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616637/how-to-relink-existing-shared-library-with-extra-object-file)), for example

   `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/librt.so /path/to/squeak`

We hope to sort this out soon-ish. Maybe you want to open an issue at https://github.com/OpenSmalltalk/

Comment: Option 1 worked for me. You have done it again Tobias. Thank you (also to those who helped in the comments). I also noticed that the library-site has the same image icon as you have here on SO ;-)

Comment: Yes, I'm the one who compiled this ;)